# Micronaut + Maven - Environment variables

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut, dotenv

I am working on a Micronaut + Maven project.
I need to parametrize some values of my application.yml such as passwords and connection strings, to avoid committing them.

I know values can be parametrized this way:

```
secret-value: '${SECRET_VALUE}'
```

But i cant find any other way to set `SECRET_VALUE` except setting bash value in .bashrc or .profile or .envoirment script files.

I would like to use a .env file somehow, in order to commit a .env.example file in git repo.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you want to define values in a `.env` file and then refer to those values in `application.yml`.  Why is it that just putting them in environment specific `yml` files won't work (`application-qa.yml`, `application-customersite.yml` etc.) and running the app with the corresponding environments activated?  Also you said you wanted to "to avoid committing them" and then said you wanted `...in order to commit a .env.example file in git repo.`.  Is it the case that you are trying to avoid storing these values in Git?

Comment: Yes, as i answered, i lost the focus of the question.
In .env.example you sould insert only non sensitive data, replacing it with example data.
So when you need to setup a new environment, you just copy the .env.example in a new .env, then you replace fake and wrong data, so you are ready to go.
This is needed in order to avoid forgetfulness.

Answer (score 1):

According to maven-resource-plugin documentation :
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

You could add a filter file in the `filters` tag of your pom file.

See `we can separate "your.name" from the POM by specifying a filter file my-filter-values.properties containing:` in the documentation above.

Comment: Will that help populate something like `secret-value: '${SECRET_VALUE}'` in `application.yml` to be read at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I may have lost the focus of the question.
the solution was simply create a .env file with required values, then run application using something like

`dotenv run ./mvnw mn:run`.

regarding @yunandtidus solution:
That is good only for "fixed" variables, such as application name, as pom values are shared between environments (assuming that we have an application-dev.yml and an application-prod.yml).
Keep in mind that, unlike .env, pom.xml **must** be committed, as any application.yml you have.

Comment: "as pom values are shared between environments" - Why do you need pom values in the running app?

Comment: Idk, maybe getting something like the current version could be useful